# View all images as an admin user

Tags: laravel

Currently I've set up a route to display the image based off whoever the current logged in user is. The user can see the images they upload as it targets the users logged in id.

### Routes

```
Route::get('/imgupload/{filename}', 'imguploadController@view');
```

### Controller

```
public function view($filename, User $user) {
    $user = $user->where('id', auth()->id())->first();

    $path = public_path() . '/app/images/'. $user->id .'/' . $filename;

    if(!File::exists($path)) abort(404);

    $file = File::get($path);

    $type = File::mimeType($path);

    $response = Response::make($file, 200);
    $response->header("Content-Type", $type);

    return $response;
}
```

However I'm looking to view all the images based off specific users as the admin user. I know the the issue is that it's looking at my admin account user id and putting that into the path and there is obviously none.

Do I need to create a new function or can I dynamically pass through a new path into this function?

Comment: There are different possible solutions. What did you try so far? Is there always one image for one user?

Comment: How do you identify your admins?

Comment: Within the user table, I've got a column for isAdmin = 1.

Answer (score 0):

When accessing as Admin you'll have to provide the image owner's `id` then do this: 
 
`Route::get('/imgupload/{filename}', 'imguploadController@view');`

```
public function view(Request $request, $filename, User $user) {

    $user = $user->where('id', auth()->id())->first();

    // Admin has to provide image owner's ID in request URL
    // like this "...imgupload/imageName?id=1234"

    if($user->isAdmin && $request->has("owner_id"))
        $path = public_path() . '/app/images/'. $request->owner_id .'/' . $filename;
    else
        $path = public_path() . '/app/images/'. $user->id .'/' . $filename;

    if(!File::exists($path)) abort(404);

    $file = File::get($path);
    $type = File::mimeType($path);

    $response = Response::make($file, 200);
    $response->header("Content-Type", $type);

    return $response;
}
```

If you can't get the owner's `id` you'll have to search all user folders for that image.